# Selenium SendKeys() and Click() silently fail after link navigation

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing automated UI tests for a simple Web app:

- https://shorturl.nakov.repl.co

The **app is really simple**: server-side logic only, no client scripts, no AJAX, not client-side frameworks.

This is my **testing scenario**:

1. Using Selenium open the app main page:
   https://shorturl.nakov.repl.co
2. Click on the link [Add URL] to navigate to: https://shorturl.nakov.repl.co/add-url
3. Fill the form at https://shorturl.nakov.repl.co/add-url and submit it
4. After the submit, assert the new element is added and is visible at the home page (https://shorturl.nakov.repl.co)

Unless I use a **dirty hack `Thread.Sleep(500)`**, the `SendKeys()` and `Click()` commands for the form elements **fail** and the form stays empty and not submitted. This happens only when the form is loaded by a link navigation. If I open it by URL, it works.

I tried many **waits and fixes**, but nothing helps, except `Thread.Sleep()`.

This problem looks like a **bug in Chromium**, because the same logic **works fine in Firefox**, but it fails the same way in **Opera** and **Edge**.

This is the **failing Selenium ChromeDriver** test:

```cs
[Test]
public void Test_AddUrl_Chrome()
{
    // Setup the Chrome Web Driver
    using (var driver = new ChromeDriver())
    {
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

        // Open the Web app and navigate to the "Add URL" page
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://shorturl.nakov.repl.co/");
        var addUrlLink = driver.FindElementByXPath("//header/a[text()='Add URL']");
        addUrlLink.Click();

        // Wait until the page "Add Short URL" is loaded --> does not help
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//main/h1[text()='Add Short URL']")));

        // Wait until the form [submit] button becomes clickable --> does not help
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(
            By.CssSelector("form button")));

        // This wait works, but is а bad practice
        //Thread.Sleep(500);

        // Fill the form and submit it
        var newUrl = "http://newurl" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".com";
        var textBoxUrl = driver.FindElementByCssSelector("input.url");

        // SendKeys() does not change the element value (unless I use Thread.Sleep())
        textBoxUrl.SendKeys(newUrl);

        var buttonCreate = driver.FindElementByCssSelector("form button");
        // Click() does not submit the form (unless I use Thread.Sleep())
        buttonCreate.Click();

        // Assert the "Short URLs" page holds the new URL
        var newUrlLink = driver.FindElementByLinkText(newUrl);
        Assert.AreEqual(newUrl + "/", newUrlLink.GetAttribute("href"));
    }
}
```

The driver log says the execution was successful. No errors, but **`SendKeys()` and `Click()` fail silently**, without an error. The form fields stay empty and the submit button is not clicked.

You can run the test on your machine to ensure it fails. It has no dependencies and the target Web app is live on the Web.

If you uncomment the `Thread.Sleep(500)` after the page navigation, the test will pass successfully.

I use the latest Chrome 88.0.4324.182 (64-bit, on Windows 10), with its corresponding 64-bit chromedriver.exe (the same version).

The same test **works fine with the FirefoxDriver**:

```cs
[Test]
public void Test_AddUrl_Firefox()
{
    // Setup the Firefox Web Driver (use ::1 for faster execution)
    var ffService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
    ffService.Host = "::1";
    using (var driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffService))
    {
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);

        // Open the Web app and navigate to the "Add URL" page
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://shorturl.nakov.repl.co/");
        var addUrlLink = driver.FindElementByXPath("//header/a[text()='Add URL']");
        addUrlLink.Click();

        // Fill the form and submit it
        var newUrl = "http://newurl" + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".com";
        var textBoxUrl = driver.FindElementByCssSelector("input.url");
        textBoxUrl.SendKeys(newUrl);
        var buttonCreate = driver.FindElementByCssSelector("form button");
        buttonCreate.Click();

        // Assert the "Short URLs" page holds the new URL
        var newUrlLink = driver.FindElementByLinkText(newUrl);
        Assert.AreEqual(newUrl + "/", newUrlLink.GetAttribute("href"));
    }
}
```

Is this a **bug** in Chromium Web driver, or I am doing **something wrong**?

Comment: I don't *think* this is an issue, but the `<title>` tag exists outside the `<head>` and `<body>` as a child of the `<html>` tag. The `<label>` tags have `for` attributes, but there are no corresponding `id` attributes on the inputs. Just out of curiosity, would fixing the HTML syntax errors fix the problems with ChromeDriver? When in doubt, check the simplest problems first.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I fixed the app, so that all its pages hold valid HTML5. This does not solve the problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: These are the ChromeDriver logs: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/attachmentText?aid=491259

Answer (score 0):

I **found a solution** for the `SendKeys()` and `Click()` silent fails: perform similar actions with JavaScript.

```
// SendKeys() does not change the element value (unless I use Thread.Sleep())
//textBoxUrl.SendKeys(newUrl);
driver.ExecuteScript($"arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '{newUrl}')", textBoxUrl);

var buttonCreate = driver.FindElementByCssSelector("form button");
// Click() does not submit the form (unless I use Thread.Sleep())
//buttonCreate.Click();
driver.ExecuteScript($"arguments[0].click()", buttonCreate);
```

The above scripts directly assign the `value` in the `textBoxUrl` field and click the `buttonCreate` button.

This is still a hack to workaround the bug I found in ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.96.

Thanks to Anton Angelov (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3501502/anton-angelov) for the help with this issue.